# how can i define variable in jqtpl-node

Tags: node.js, jquery-templates, express

I using express js with jqtpl and i need to define temporary variable in jqtlp to keep some information from each loop. This is my try:

```
{{var tmp = ""}}
{{tmp = ""}}
${var tmp = ""}
```

Always my try doesn't work. How can i define variable? It's possibble ? Mybe not ?

Comment: This isn't possible. You could output that info (ie index) and then manipulate it on the client side via javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define local variable by evaluating expression in template tag:

```
${( $local = 'Local variable' ),''}
```